# How to enable audio in Java 3D?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, java-3d

Whenever I try to run any sound related code in Java 3D, I get the following exception stacktrace :-

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No AudioDevice specified
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.Viewer.createAudioDevice(Viewer.java:986)
    at threedimentional.collision.SoundBug.init(SoundBug.java:229)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame.run(MainFrame.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Java 3D: audio is disabled
```

The code snippet that produced it is as follows :-

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse
        .getPreferredConfiguration();

    canvas = new Canvas3D(config);
    add("Center", canvas);

    // Create a simple scene and attach it to the virtual universe
    BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraph();
    u = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);

    // set up sound
    AudioDevice ad = u.getViewer().createAudioDevice();
```

What to do ?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal code sample that produces this Exception? It helps to identify the problem.

Comment: Updated the post with the code. The last line is the one which is giving the exception.